# Memcached consistent hashing not working with 3 of 4 servers down

Tags: php, caching, memcached, consistent-hashing, libketama

## Story

I have 3 memcached servers running where I shutdown the one or the other to investigate how PHP-memcached behaves upon a server not beeing reachable.

I have defined 4 servers in PHP, 1 to simulate a server that is mostly offline (spare server). When I shutdown 1 server (=> 2 are still online), the third `->get()` gives me a result.

When I shutdown one more server (=> 1 is still online), it won't find objects pushed to that last server.

## Sample output

**First run, 3 of 4 servers up:**

```
Entity not found in cache on 1st try: NOT FOUND
Entity not found in cache on 2nd try: NOT FOUND
Entity not found in cache on 3rd try: NOT FOUND
Entity not found in cache on 4th try: NOT FOUND
```

**Second run, 3 of 4 servers up:**

```
Entity found in Cache: SUCCESS
```

**Third run, 2 of 4 servers up:**

```
Entity not found in cache on 1st try: CONNECTION FAILURE
Entity not found in cache on 2nd try: SERVER IS MARKED DEAD
Entity not found in cache on 3rd try: NOT FOUND
Entity not found in cache on 4th try: NOT FOUND
```

**Fourth run, 1 of 4 servers up:**

```
Entity not found in cache on 1st try: CONNECTION FAILURE
Entity not found in cache on 2nd try: SERVER IS MARKED DEAD
Entity not found in cache on 3rd try: CONNECTION FAILURE
Entity not found in cache on 4th try: SERVER IS MARKED DEAD
```

Although there is one server left online and I do push my object to memcached everytime it does not find any in cache, it is not able to find  the key anymore.

I think it should also work with only a single server left.

**Can you explain this behaviour to me?**

It looks like it is not possible to implement something that is **safe even when I shutdown 19 of 20 servers**.

Sidequestion: libketama is not really maintained anymore, is it still good to use it? The logic behind the lib was rather good and is also used in the varnish caching server.

## Appendix

My Script:

```
<?php
require_once 'CachableEntity.php';
require_once 'TestEntity.php';

echo PHP_EOL;

$cache = new Memcached();
$cache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_LIBKETAMA_COMPATIBLE, true);
$cache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_DISTRIBUTION, Memcached::DISTRIBUTION_CONSISTENT);
$cache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_SERVER_FAILURE_LIMIT, 1);
$cache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_REMOVE_FAILED_SERVERS, true);
$cache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_AUTO_EJECT_HOSTS, true);

$cache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_TCP_NODELAY, true);
//$cache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_RETRY_TIMEOUT, 10);

$cache->addServers([
    ['localhost', '11212'],
    ['localhost', '11213'],
    ['localhost', '11214'],
    ['localhost', '11215'], // always offline
]);


$entityId = '/test/test/article_123456789.test';

$entity = new TestEntity($entityId);

$found = false;

$cacheKey = $entity->getCacheKey();

$cacheResult = $cache->get($cacheKey);
if (empty($cacheResult)) {
    echo 'Entity not found in cache on 1st try: ' . $cache->getResultMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    
    $cacheResult = $cache->get($cacheKey);
    if (empty($cacheResult)) {
        echo 'Entity not found in cache on 2nd try: ' . $cache->getResultMessage(), PHP_EOL;
        
        $cacheResult = $cache->get($cacheKey);
        if (empty($cacheResult)) {
            echo 'Entity not found in cache on 3rd try: ' . $cache->getResultMessage(), PHP_EOL;
            
            $cacheResult = $cache->get($cacheKey);
            if (empty($cacheResult)) {
                echo 'Entity not found in cache on 4th try: ' . $cache->getResultMessage(), PHP_EOL;
                
                $entity
                    ->setTitle('TEST')
                    ->setText('Hellow w0rld. Lorem Orem Rem Em M IpsuM')
                    ->setUrl('http://www.google.com/content-123456789.html');
                
                $cache->set($cacheKey, $entity->serialize(), 120);
            }
        }
        else { $found = true; }
    }
    else { $found = true; }
}
else { $found = true; }


if ($found === true) {
    echo 'Entity found in Cache: ' . $cache->getResultMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    $entity->unserialize($cacheResult);
    echo 'Title: ' . $entity->getTitle(), PHP_EOL;
}

echo PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The behaviour you are experiencing is consistent. When a server is not available it's first marked with a failure and then marked as dead.

The problem is that apparently it would only be coherent if you had set `Memcached::OPT_SERVER_FAILURE_LIMIT` value to 2 while you have set this to 1. This would have explained why you have two error lines per unreachable server (`CONNECTION FAILURE`, `SERVER IS MARKED AS DEAD`)

This seems to be related with timeout. Adding a `usleep()` after a failure with a matching `OPT_RETRY_TIMEOUT` value will enable the server to be dropped from the list (see the [following bug comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/libmemcached/+bug/1158676/comments/4))

- The value does not replicate to the next server because only keys are distributed.
- Note that `OPT_LIBKETAMA_COMPATIBLE` does not use libketama, but only reproduces the same algorithm, which means that it does not matter if libketama is no longer active while this is the recommended configuration [in PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.constants.php):

> It is highly recommended to enable this option if you want to use consistent hashing, and it may be enabled by default in future releases.

**EDIT:**
In my understanding of your post, the message "Entity found in Cache: SUCCESS" only appears on the second run (1 server offline) because there's no change from the previous command and the server hosting this key is still available (so memcached consider from the key that the value is stored on either the 1st, 2nd or 3rd server). Let's call those servers John, George, Ringo and Paul.

In the third run, at start, memcached deduces from the key which one of the four servers owns the value (e.g. John). It asks John twice before giving up because it's now off. Its algorithm then only considers 3 servers (not knowing that Paul is already dead) and deduces that George should contain the value.

George answers twice that it does not contain the value and then store it.

But on the fourth run, John, George and Paul are off. Memcached tries John twice, and then tries George twice. It then stores in Ringo.

The problem here is that the unavailable servers are not memorized between different runs, and that within the same run you have to ask twice a server before it's removed.

Comment: Look into the script, when it does not found the key 4 times, it will push the object (`$cache->set()`). This works with up to 2 of 4 servers beeing offline, but it does not anymore with 3 of 4 servers beeing offline.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I edited my answer. As the values of a server are lost when it goes offline, it's perfectly normal that the only time it works is on the second run (same configuration as in the first run). As long as Memcached will require 2 calls before falling over to the next server, this will require up to 8 calls with 4 servers. [Memcached::Getstats](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/memcached.getstats.php) may help to initialize the connection

Comment: I have already expanded my script to do 8 tries (on 4 server) but I forgot the `else { $found = true; }` which is why it didn't work as expected -.-

Answer (score 0):

**Redundancy**

Since Memcached 3.0.0, there is a redundancy configuration.

- It can be made in the extension config file.

/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/memcached.ini  (may be different among operating systems)

```
memcache.redundancy=2
```

- with ini_set('memcache.redundancy', 2)

This parameter is not really documented, you may replace "2" by the number of servers, this will add slight overhead with extra writes.

**Loosing 19/20 servers**

With redundancy, you may loose some servers and keep a "read success".

Notes:

- loosing 95% of a server pool will cause a stress on the remaining ones.
- Cache servers are made for performances, ["a large number of servers can slow down a client from a few angles"](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Performance#maximum-number-of-nodes-in-a-cluster)

**libketama**

Github repository has not received any commits since 2014. Libketama is looking for a new maintainer https://github.com/RJ/ketama

Comment: This does not explain the behaviour of my script. It also does not answer why 1 of 5 servers do not return my pushed object. The variable redundancy works for memcache, not for memcached. The answer is not helpful and far from beeing worth 400 rep, sorry to say.